# If a string is used as a key in a hashtable , how does it provide O(1) time access to the contents corresponding to that key?

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity

Since we need to traverse the string itself , how can a hashtable provide O(1) access ?

Comment: You are technically correct - it is not O(1), it is more kind of O(k), where k is length of the string. But in basic discussions about complexity, you ignore k and focus on n (number of elements in collection). You are interested in how your algorithm behaves when number of elements changes, key length is assumed to be invariant. Of course, when you will be talking about some non-trivial algorithms working on strings, then n will be the length of string. And for things like tries, k comes into picture even in very basic analysis.

Comment: You could use a hashfunction that considers only the first 8 characters or so. With a 'bad' dataset you will get a lot of collisions, but if your strings usually differ in the first characters, then such a hashfunction can help you avoid O(len(string))

Answer (score 0):

> Since we need to traverse the string itself

You don’t, if you create a hash function to convert the string to an integer and use it as the index.

Example: https://github.com/marioluan/java-data-structures/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/marioluan/datastructures/symboltable/hash/LinearProbingHashTable.java

Comment: How can we do that ?

Comment: Take a look at the GitHub repository, there is an example there.